# Transparent text on opaque background

Tags: html, css, opacity

I've seen tons of questions that are the exact opposite of what I need. I want a button, that when hovered over, will have an opaque background, but text that is the color of the background image of the body.

Comment: I don't have my computer with me. I tried setting the background color to what I needed, then setting the color to transparent, but the transparent text just showed the background. I'm working with a button that is directly in the body element, which has a background image

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to do it with a bit o' jquery.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/qj9tvrtf/)

```js
$(".filter").hover(function() {
  $(this).css("opacity", ".8");
}, function() {
  $(this).css("opacity", ".4");
});
```

```css
#box {
  background-image: url("http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/despicableme/images/7/7a/Gru_thinking.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130901203940");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

.filter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

p:hover {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

a{text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">

  <div id="box">

    <div class="filter">
      <p>
        hello my name is rachel
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with that.

```
body{background-color:#000;}`
button{
color:white;`
```

`background-color:red;}
button:hover, button:focus{
color:transparent;
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,.5)}`